# Kohana: How to send internal request like external from ajax?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.2

I have some controller Ajax. That controller make some validation of request and if it not from ajax returns error message.

Function is_ajax() check header X-Requested-With and return true or false.

I'm use this link from ajax and all work.

/ajax/somecontroller/someaction

When i try use it internal - i have my own validation error - not ajax request.

There is my code:

```
$deleted = Request::factory("/ajax/somecontroller/someaction")
                        ->headers("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        ->headers('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH', 'XmlHttpRequest')
                        ->headers('X-Requested-With', 'XmlHttpRequest')                            
                        ->method(Request::POST)
                        ->post(array(
                            "id_zone_comp" => $id_zone_comp
                        ))
                        ->execute()->body();
```

I send needed heades but have error.

How to send internal request like external?

Kohana 3.2.

---

Of course I can process internal queries such as Ajax just give them access after is_internal(), but this is not answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is related to the fact that it is in fact an internal request. Because of that the headers you're sending are not populating `$_SERVER` environment info array. They're kept inside `$this->request->headers()` instead.

The ajax check is done in based on $_SERVER contents, like this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']))
{
    // Typically used to denote AJAX requests
    $requested_with = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'];
}
```

The only solution that would not include `is_internal()` check would be to make this request an external one and to do that you'd have to set the request URL to include protocol (`http://`) and full domain name - essentially a full address. Then, the request will populate $_SERVER array with new headers and `is_ajax()` should let it through.